# Семантический антоним пословице "Рыба гниет с головы"

Tags: лексика, фразеология, выбор-слов, антонимы

Существует пословица:

> Рыба гниет с головы.

Отбросив её опциональное продолжение, можно заключить, что негативные изменения распространяются с высших уровней.

Есть также другая:

> Каков поп, таков и приход.

У неё имеется схожее значение, но не акцентирующее на характере изменений. Т. е. каков начальник, таковы и подчиненные.

*Существует ли пословица с подобным значением, но с акцентном на распространение позитивных изменений с высших уровней?*

Comment: Каков поп, таков и приход... В православной среде содержание этого суждения никогда не получает негативной окраски.

Comment: А вот у (православных) героев Пушкина - негативная. *Лицо Кирила Петровича мрачилось. - Ты, кажется, меня господином не признаешь, добро, - отвечал он. - А что ты делал в моем саду?- Малину крал, - отвечал мальчик с большим равнодушием.- Ага, слуга в барина, каков поп, таков и приход, а малина разве растет у меня на дубах?*

Comment: Не все крещённые по рождению — православные в жизни.

Comment: Значит, вопрос в том, кого считать православным в жизни. Но давайте его не будем обсуждать, так как он не по теме русского языка.

Comment: Давайте не спускать и не допускать глумления, какими бы мы не были радетелями русского языка.

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, что вот эти пословицы и поговорки характеризуются положительным отношением к "верхам" (начальству, руководству). Последнюю я отношу конкретно к определению "распространение позитивных изменений с высших уровней":

Правдивый начальник оценивает всякого по заслугам.
Без запевалы и песня не поется.
Наказом воеводы рать крепка.
Лиса хороша своим хвостом, а начальник своей распорядительностью (башк.).
Без матки рой не держится.
Войску без вождя на войне не выпадет счастья (аварская).
Без столбов и забор не стоит.
Где нет кошки, мыши резвятся.
Без пастуха и овцы не стадо.
Красна рать воеводою.
Без предводителя войско гибнет (белор.).
Если вожак умен — ты не заблудишься (кирг.).
Без перевясла и веник рассыпался.
У лихого жеребца косяк цел.
**При храбром начальнике и трус храбреет.**

**Дополнение**
Есть в доме хозяин — бедности не знаем (исп.).
Добрый пастух не о себе печётся, о скотине.
**У хорошего хозяина и свинка — господинка** (укр.).

Comment: "При храбром начальнике и трус храбреет." - это хороший пример пословицы, которая имеет черты, упомянутые в вопросе, благодарю Вас. Несомненно, считаю этот ответ полезным, но воздержусь от его принятия, т.к. частотность употребления этой пословицы низка (порядка 250 абсолютных вхождений при поиске в Гугл), соответственно, и универсальность применения, которая ограничивается чертой храбрости.

Comment: Значение пословицы гораздо шире, нежели только "храбрость". Можно использовать в этом контексте и другие положительные качества, например: **При умном начальнике и глупец умнеет.**

Comment: Ну, ум сложнее поддается распространению :)). Может, лучше про честность?

Answer (score 3):

В пословицах отношение к власти в основном негативное. Но кое-что удалось найти. Не о распространении позитивных изменений, но о хороших руководителях.

Где царь, тут и правда. (http://millionstatusov.ru/poslovitsi/tsar.html)

Коли царь бога знает, бог и царя и народ знает. (http://millionstatusov.ru/poslovitsi/tsar.html)

Артель атаманом крепка. (http://www.ermak.su/pogovorki/o_kollektive.htm)

Атаманом громада крепка. (http://www.kazakirossii.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=295)

Без атамана казак сирота. (http://www.kazakirossii.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=295)